# Observing particular Port for measuring network game performance

Tags: network-programming, benchmarking, port, load-testing

How can i check/inspect the performance of some network application via observing the port it used,i want to test the performance of my network game. is it some way, or is it some practice like this?

If my game is connect to  port 1009, how can i check the different parameters data outflow , inflow and other metrics on this port.

any ideas,

thanks,

Jibbylala

Comment: You could ask this over on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ but you'd need to be much more specific about the metrics you want to capture and why.

Comment: NO, I don't think the question need any more information as you mentioned, and  didn't get the idea to take that as non software development question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you just need a [Packet Sniffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_sniffer#Notable_packet_analyzers)